# Mocking void objects without passing them

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have written the following method:

```
public void checkIfPlansPublishMailShouldBeSent(
        boolean allPlansPublished, String currentPhase,
        String chaseIterationCount, LoadConfig config,
        String clientFolderName, LoggerHandler logger){
    if(allPlansPublished){
        sendPlansPublishMail(
            currentPhase, chaseIterationCount, config, clientFolderName,logger);
    }else{
        System.out.println(
            "allPlansPublish is set to false, Plans Publish Mail not sent out");
    }
}
```

I need to write a JUnit test for it. I also need to mock `sendPlansPublishMail` as that would send an email if it is run.

I'm using Mockito to mock the Object the method belongs to (ReportSyncCheck).

Is there a way to verify that `sendPlansPublishMail` is being called without having to pass a mock object into `checkIfPlansPublishMailShouldBeSent` as a parameter?

Open to other methods of testing too. As I need to write of JUnit tests I don't want to have to pass in every Object I need as a parameter as I imagine my methods will have large method signatures.

I have written a JUnit test that does pass the mock object as a parameter, which I'm trying to avoid:

```
public class checkIfPlansPublishMailShouldBeSentTest {

    ReportSyncCheck mockRSC;
    ReportSyncCheck RSCtoTest;
    LoggerHandler mockLogger;
    LoadConfig mockLoadConfig;
    boolean allPlansPublished;
    String currentPhase;
    String chaseIterationCount;
    String clientFolderName;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockRSC = mock(ReportSyncCheck.class);
        RSCtoTest = new ReportSyncCheck();
        mockLogger = mock(LoggerHandler.class);
        mockLoadConfig = mock(LoadConfig.class);
        currentPhase = "Time Submission Chase";
        chaseIterationCount ="1";
        clientFolderName = "TestClient";

    }

    @Test
    public void testMailMethodcalledWhenAllPlansPublishedIsSetToFalse() {
        allPlansPublished =true;
        RSCtoTest.checkIfPlansPublishMailShouldBeSent(allPlansPublished, currentPhase, chaseIterationCount, mockLoadConfig, clientFolderName, mockLogger,mockRSC);
        verify(mockRSC).sendPlansPublishMail(currentPhase, chaseIterationCount, mockLoadConfig, clientFolderName, mockLogger);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMailMethodcalledWhenAllPlansPublishedIsSetToTrue() {
        allPlansPublished =false;
        RSCtoTest.checkIfPlansPublishMailShouldBeSent(allPlansPublished, currentPhase, chaseIterationCount, mockLoadConfig, clientFolderName, mockLogger,mockRSC);
        verify(mockRSC,times(0)).sendPlansPublishMail(currentPhase, chaseIterationCount, mockLoadConfig, clientFolderName, mockLogger);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check `org.mockito.Mockito.verify` and `org.mockito.BDDMockito.given` That's what you want.

Also nice examples are on http://gojko.net/2009/10/23/mockito-in-six-easy-examples/ and http://www.javahotchocolate.com/notes/mockito.html

Comment: Hi JiriS, thanks for your comment, Ive given it a read, and both examples seem to require a mock object being passed in as a parameter.                                                                                          @Test
 public void OutputStreamWriter_Closes_OutputStream_on_Close()
   throws IOException{
  OutputStream mock=mock(OutputStream.class);
  OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(mock);
  osw.close();
  verify(mock).close();
 }

Comment: Any ideas on how to do it without altering the method signature?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Mockito to mock your dependencies, so that you can focus your test on the class under test. Good.

The most usual way to inject dependencies in an object is at construction time, using it's constructor. Build your service object injecting all it's dependencies into the constructor of the class:

```
public class MyService {
  private final MyDao dao;

  public MyService(MyDao dao){
    this.dao = dao;
  }

  public String myMethod(){
    return dao.find();
  }
}
```

Alternatively, a popular approach is to inject dependencies using setters:

```
  public class MyOtherService {
  private MyDao dao;

  public void setDao(MyDao dao){
    this.dao = dao;
  }

  public String myMethod(){
    return dao.find();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alban, If I have a method that uses, say, 5 methods, would that mean my constructor will have 5 method parameters? Im interested in the setter approach you described, would you be willing to provide an example please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need spy for partial behaviour.

```
public class checkIfPlansPublishMailShouldBeSentTest {


    ReportSyncCheck mockRSC;

    LoggerHandler mockLogger;
    LoadConfig mockLoadConfig;
    boolean allPlansPublished;
    String currentPhase;
    String chaseIterationCount;
    String clientFolderName;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockRSC = spy(ReportSyncCheck.class);

        mockLogger = mock(LoggerHandler.class);
        mockLoadConfig = mock(LoadConfig.class);
        currentPhase = "Time Submission Chase";
        chaseIterationCount ="1";
        clientFolderName = "TestClient";

    }


    @Test
    public void testMailMethodcalledWhenAllPlansPublishedIsSetToFalse() {
        doNothing().when(mockRSC).sendPlansPublishMail(currentPhase, chaseIterationCount, mockLoadConfig, clientFolderName, mockLogger);
        allPlansPublished =true;
        mockRSC.checkIfPlansPublishMailShouldBeSent(allPlansPublished, currentPhase, chaseIterationCount, mockLoadConfig, clientFolderName, mockLogger,mockRSC);
        verify(mockRSC).sendPlansPublishMail(currentPhase, chaseIterationCount, mockLoadConfig, clientFolderName, mockLogger);
    }
```